# Parsing a string field

Tags: ruby

I have these Syslog messages:

```
N 4000000 PROD     15307 23:58:12.13 JOB78035 00000000  $HASP395 GGIVJS27 ENDED\r
NI0000000 PROD     15307 23:58:13.41 STC81508 00000200  $A  J78036            /* CA-JOBTRAC JOB RELEASE */\r
```

I would like to parse these messages into various fields in a Hash, e.g.:

```
 event['recordtype']  #=> "N"
 event['routingcode'] #=> "4000000"
 event['systemname']  #=> "PROD"
 event['datetime']    #=> "15307 23:58:12.13"
 event['jobid']       #=> "JOB78035"
 event['flag']        #=> "00000000"
 event['messageid']   #=> "$HASP395"
 event['logmessage']  #=> "$HASP395 GGIVJS27 ENDED\r"
```

This is the code I have currently:

```
message = event["message"];
if message.to_s != "" then
  if message[2] == " " then
    array = message.split(%Q[ ]);
    event[%q[recordtype]] = array[0];
    event[%q[routingcode]] = array[1];
    event[%q[systemname]] = array[2];
    event[%q[datetime]] = array[3] + " " +array[4];
    event[%q[jobid]] = message[38,8];
    event[%q[flags]] = message[47,8];
    event[%q[messageid]] = message[57,8];
    event[%q[logmessage]] = message[56..-1];
  else
    array = message.split(%Q[ ]);
    event[%q[recordtype]] = array[0][0,2];
    event[%q[routingcode]] = array[0][2..-1];
    event[%q[systemname]] = array[1];
    event[%q[datetime]] = array[2] + " "+array[3];
    event[%q[jobid]] = message[38,8];
    event[%q[flags]] = message[47,8];
    event[%q[messageid]] = message[57,8];
    event[%q[logmessage]] = message[56..-1];
  end
end
```

I'm looking to improve the above code. I think I could use a regular expression, but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Can you give an example of the hashmap that you would like to produce?

Comment: Why are you using `%q[...]` and `%Q[...]` literals?

Comment: Your use of the redundant semicolons gives a very bad impression.

Comment: Using `if` with a negative predicate `!=` is also bad.

Comment: @sawa Your sweeping statement about `if` is too general. In this case `unless` seems like the correct choice. But in some cases, `if` reads better. See https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/issues/329.

Comment: I guess changing the definition of `event` is no choice? If you can do this, and if the set of names of the "fields" in `event` (i.e. `jobid`, `flags` etc.) is fixed, you could define event to be a Ruby Struct, and write the assignments i.e. as `event.jobid=message[38,8]`, which is a bit more readable and gives some protection against typing errors.

Comment: event['recordtype'] = "N"
event['routingcode'] = "4000000"
event['systemname'] = "PROD"
event['datetime'] = "15307 23:58:12.13"
event['jobid'] = "JOB78035"
event['flag'] = "00000000"
event['messageid'] = "$HASP395"
event['logmessage'] = "$HASP395 GGIVJS27 ENDED\r" this is the output which i am expecting...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't put code or data into comments. It makes it really difficult to help you as we have to read every comment, then try to figure out where the data or code applies to your question. Instead, edit your question and put that information into the text where it would have gone if you'd originally entered it. Please don't put "Edit" or "Updated" tags in the text. We're creating entries in a programmers reference, not having a discussion, and if we need to see where something changed we can look at the revision history.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We can't run your code, so helping debug it is not possible. We need the minimal code and input data necessary to demonstrate the problem along with your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `split(' ')` or a default `split` to process your fields because you are dealing with columnar data that has fields that have no whitespace between them, resulting in your array being off. Instead, you have to pick apart each record by columns.

There are many ways to do that but the simplest and probably fastest, is indexing into a string and grabbing n characters:

```
'foo'[0, 1] # => "f"
'foo'[1, 2] # => "oo"
```

The first means "starting at index 0 in the string, grab one character." The second means "starting at index 1 in the string, grab two characters."

Alternately, you could tell Ruby to extract by ranges:

```
'foo'[0 .. 0] # => "f"
'foo'[1 .. 2] # => "oo"
```

These are [documented in the String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

This makes writing code that's easily understood:

```
record_type  = message[ 0  .. 1  ].rstrip
routing_code = message[ 2  .. 8  ]
system_name  = message[ 10 .. 17 ]
```

Once you have your fields captured add them to a hash:

```
{
  'recordtype'  => record_type,
  'routingcode' => routing_code,
  'systemname'  => system_name,
  'datetime'    => date_time,
  'jobid'       => job_id,
  'flags'       => flags,
  'messageid'   => message_id,
  'logmessage'  => log_message,
}
```

While you could use a regular expression there's not much gained using one, it's just another way of doing it. If you were picking data out of free-form text it'd be more useful, but in columnar data it tends to result in visual noise that makes maintenance more difficult. I'd recommend simply determining your columns then cutting the data you need based on those from each line.

Comment: You could go one step further and define the fields as ranges in a template, like `recordtype: 0..1, routing_code: 2..8` and later use that to extract all the fields using `map` and `Hash[]`.

Comment: Yep, but I didn't want to overwhelm the OP so I figured it's best to start with simple text extraction.

Comment: For sure! Just showing how this can be iterated on a bit more. Ruby makes doing tranforms like that pretty elegant and simple.